# Can I declare global pug variable in Vue

Tags: vue.js, pug

I have a `.jade` source files and want to insert it into Vue app.

In sources I have the following code:

_mixins.jade:

```
- var domain = "example.com"
```

index.jade:

```
include _mixins
title #{domain}
```

And it, obviously, works.

What I want - is:

App.vue:

```
- var domain = "example.com"

div#app
  HelloWorld
```

HelloWorld.vue:

```
h1 #{domain}
```

Is it possible at all? Or I'd have to have separate file with mixins and include it to every component, that'd use mixins and global variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [@takeshi-tokugawa-yd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4818123/takeshi-tokugawa-yd)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73834712/7149107).

To add a global variable, you need to add a property to the `global` object. As soon as you have this field in `global`, pug will automatically resolve it without the need to touch its configuration.

Here is an example:

1. `vite.config.ts`

   ```
   (global as any).domain = 'example.com';
   (global as any).protocol = 'https';
   ```
2. `index.pug`

   ```
   h1 #{protocol}://#{domain}
   ```

---

Hovewer, it is far from implicitly included mixin with variables as in the question. It's more an ugly hack, because you need to modify the `global` object. Thus, I think that it's not possible to achieve what I wanted in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The specific method is dependent on your project building system.

- If you are using the Vite, define the globals in dedicated property of first parameter of `pugPlugin(options, locals)` of [vite-plugin-pug](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-pug).
- If you are using the [pug-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pug-loader) for Webpack, specify your global variables in `globals` option.
- If you are using the [pug-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pug-plugin) for Wepback, it has [own loader](https://github.com/webdiscus/pug-loader) with [`globals`](https://github.com/webdiscus/pug-loader#globals) option.